# How do I get the Ivy version from a Ant build.xml

Tags: java, ant, ivy, build.xml

I'm at my wits end here... I just want to be able to get the version of Ivy from a build.xml file because we require 2.2.0+.  It should be simple but I haven't been able to find a way to do it... Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Running an ivy resolve task will set a series of ivy properties:

```
<target name="version">
    <ivy:resolve/>
    <echoproperties prefix="ivy."/>
</target>
```

Example output:

```
[echoproperties] #Ant properties
[echoproperties] #Fri Nov 08 21:21:08 GMT 2013
[echoproperties] ivy.basedir=/home/mark/project
..
..
[echoproperties] ivy.version=2.3.0
```